# Ghostscript invalid font error

Tags: linux, pdf, gnuplot, fedora, ghostscript

I have some problem with ghostscript or maybe fonts in my system. 
I am using Fedora 17. What I have tried to convert ps file to pdf
http://krajniak.info/tmp/intro.ps
unfortunately what I have got is:

```
Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
Operand stack:
   Symbol-Oblique   Symbol
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1894   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1852   2   4   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1160/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:174/256(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
Current file position is 15269
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I have the same error with displaing this file:
evince intro.ps

```
[teodor@lukrecja graphs]$ evince intro.ps 
invalidfont -10
invalidfont -10

(evince:5621): EvinceDocument-CRITICAL **: ev_document_misc_pixbuf_from_surface: assertion `surface' failed

(evince:5621): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
invalidfont -10

(evince:5621): EvinceDocument-CRITICAL **: ev_document_misc_pixbuf_from_surface: assertion `surface' failed

(evince:5621): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
invalidfont -10
```

I have tried with uninstalling freetype-infinality, also with enable "Type 1" fonts in /etc/fonts/infinality/infinality.conf but with out any results.

Results of gs -v :

```
Search path:
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/Resource/Init :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/lib :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/9.05/Resource/Font :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/fonts : /usr/share/fonts/default/ghostscript :
   /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1 : /usr/share/fonts/default/amspsfnt/pfb :
   /usr/share/fonts/default/cmpsfont/pfb : /usr/share/fonts :
   /usr/share/ghostscript/conf.d : /etc/ghostscript :
   /etc/ghostscript/9.05 : /usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-CNS1 :
   /usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-GB1 :
   /usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-Japan1 :
   /usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-Japan2 :
   /usr/share/poppler/cMap/Adobe-Korea1
```

**Solved**
Simple remove all tex-{fonts} and wine-{fonts}, then reinstall ghostscript. Currently my /usr/share/fonts contains such folders:

```
abattis-cantarell
cjkuni-uming
default
dejavu
google-droid
jomolhari
jsmath-fonts
khmeros
liberation
lklug
lohit-assamese
lohit-bengali
lohit-devanagari
lohit-gujarati
lohit-kannada
lohit-oriya
lohit-punjabi
lohit-tamil
lohit-telugu
nhn-nanum
opensymbol
paktype-naqsh
paratype-pt-sans
sil-abyssinica
sil-padauk
smc
stix
thai-scalable
vlgothic
wqy-zenhei
```

Maybe someone has some suggestion, what I should do.
Bye.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Symbol font is invalid. Also it looks like your Ghostscript is not using built-in fonts (and ROM file system) and is exclusively, or preferentially, using system fonts.

My copy of Ghostscript uses the fonts shipped with GS, and built into a ROM file system, and your file works perfectly.